# With latest fflib, do TriggerHandlers become service class consumers? If so what happens to UoW?

Tags: apex, design-patterns, domain-layer

[With the latest fflib](https://github.com/apex-enterprise-patterns/fflib-apex-common-samplecode/commit/413fbccae014c014144e1ba481fc071cf8fbe2ea), the trigger handler and domain logic were separated. I can see from the changes to the repo that previously, the Opportunities.cls domain class' `onAfterInsert()` method updates the account's fields by instantiating a UoW and an Accounts.cls domain class and calling its appropriate method and passing the UoW to finally commit the change.

Now with the separation, the logic in `updateOpportunityActivityOnAccount`, which is called with `onAfterInsert()`, calls the `updateOpportunityActivity` method on AccountsService.cls.

### Question 1

*Is it correct to say the TriggerHandler classes can call service methods if cross object updating is required?*

### Question 2

As I understand it, public domain methods take unitOfWork as a parameter. This becomes confusing if the TriggerHandler class is going to call a domain's method in a before context where unitOfWork is not needed. For example, consider the following scenario where the TriggerHandler class calls a method on the context record's domain class, but has to instantiate an unnecessary unitOfWork due to calling context being from `onBeforeInsert`.

InteractionsTriggerHandler.cls

```
    public override void onBeforeInsert()
    {
        fflib_ISObjectUnitOfWork uow = new fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork(new Schema.SObjectType[] { Interaction__c.SObjectType }); 

        // Assign ownership
        IInteractions interactions = Interactions.newInstance(this.records);
        interactions.assignOwnership(uow);
    }
```

Interactions.cls

```
    public void assignOwnership(fflib_ISObjectUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        // Collect channels
        Map<Id, Channel__c> channelsById = 
            new Map<Id, Channel__c>( (List<Channel__c>) Application.Selector.selectById( getChannelIds() ) );

        for (Interaction__c interaction : (List<Interaction__c>) getRecords())
        {
            // Get channel
            Channel__c channel = channelsById.get(interaction.Interaction_Channel__c);

            // Assign ownership
            interaction.OwnerId = channel.OwnerId;

            uow.registerDirty(interaction);
        }
    }
```

Of course, the unitOfWork parameter on the domain class is useful for when the method is called from a service such as InteractionsServiceImpl, but is not always necessary as seen above. *What is the correct way of handling that?*

Comment: These questions are better posed on the apex-commons GitHub issues page where the fflib thoughtLeaders hang out

Comment: Thanks! I have [done so](https://github.com/apex-enterprise-patterns/fflib-apex-common/issues/443). Will close this question if it's answered there.